# Dynamically group clients by location, limited to a maximum size

Tags: java, performance, list, collections, big-o

So I am working on a project that requires a collection of clients to be iterated through for updating, with each client requiring an update packet for every other client within proximity. I want to be able to do this in a fast way since updates will happen for a large amount of clients, at an often-occurring interval.

My original plan of attack was to create regions based on client locations, updating each client only with the other clients in their region. This would entail a `LinkedList<Region>`, with the Region having its own list of clients which would update among each other. One problem with this method was that some regions could have 1 client, while others could have 1000. Another level of difficulty arose from the fact that clients will constantly be moving (thus changing location and Region). These problems could be avoided if there was a way to modify the list while iterating through it, possibly splitting elements when a region gets too large.

Next I thought of creating one large `List<Client>` that held all players, which was constantly sorted based on location. Then to update client at index `n` of the list with the closest 20 clients, I would only iterate `n-10` and `n+10` from their current index. I don't really like this method as much since if there was a 21st client in a closeby area, they could be ignored even though they had equal distance to the client at `n` as the one at `n+10`. It also seemed slow to have to resort all the clients every tick.

In terms of speed, which of these methods provides better performance? Additionally, are there any other Java collections I should consider? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly prefer the first method. Sorting the entire list every tick is going to end up being a very bad idea time-wise, which rules out the second method.

To solve the concurrency issues, you should make a copy of the `LinkedList<Reigon>` before updating it in a thread. That way you will allow `Client`s to change their `Reigon` at the same time as updates are being pushed out to each `Reigon`.

Another note is that if you plan on retrieving an arbitrary `Reigon` from the `LinkedList<Reigon>` (for example, when you move a `Client` from one `Reigon` to another) you should look into some kind of a hash set. It will increase performance greatly when retrieving an arbitrary element from the middle of the list, especially if the list is large.